# iPhoto '11 vs. iPhoto '09 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, photos.app

In iPhoto '09 looking at a picture in an event, I could hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get back to the event. It appears that this no longer works in iPhoto '11.

Is there a different keyboard shortcut that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit, it seems that <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> works.

Answer (score 0):

All keyboard shortcuts can be found on Apple's [iPhoto Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.apple.com/support/iphoto/shortcuts/) website.

Comment: I disagree. The website you link to doesn't show the Cmd-LeftArrow combination and yet it works.